# iPhone - a question about dispatch timers and timing

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have to fire a method at regular intervals (every 0.16 seconds). The tolerance can be, lets say up to 30%. Closer to 16 ms, better.

I have tried NSTimers but they are not precise enough. I have tried threads and also had the same problem. I am now trying dispatch timers.

I am using this code provided by Apple:

```
dispatch_source_t CreateDispatchTimer(uint64_t interval,
              uint64_t leeway,
              dispatch_queue_t queue,
              dispatch_block_t block)
{
   dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER,
                                                     0, 0, queue);
   if (timer)
   {
      dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval, leeway);
      dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
      dispatch_resume(timer);
   }
   return timer;
}

void MyCreateTimer()
{
   dispatch_source_t aTimer = CreateDispatchTimer(0.16 * NSEC_PER_SEC, //0.16 ms
                               0.048 * NSEC_PER_SEC, //30% tolerance
                               dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                               ^{ MyPeriodicTask(); });

   // Store it somewhere for later use.
    if (aTimer)
    {
        MyStoreTimer(aTimer);
    }
}
```

I am measuring the intervals and getting these times between executions of MyPeriodicTask():

```
0.148,  0.165,  0.148,  0.167,  0.167,  0.187,  0.167,  
0.167,  0.146,  0.166,  0.167,  0.167,  0.188,  0.145,  
0.243,  0.331,  0.047,  0.045,  0.168,  0.165,  0.167, 
0.166,  0.167,  0.167,  0.169,  0.165,  0.166,  0.169,  
0.165,  0.203,  0.130,  0.167,  0.167,  0.167,  0.167,  
0.167,  0.167,  0.167,  0.167,  0.167
```

Notice that the method is being fired more or less within the 16ms range.

considering the 30% range, I was expecting values between 0.118 and 0.214 ms, but notice values as 0.243 and 0.331 far above the range and others like 0.047 and 0.045!!!! How can the method fire before the timer interval???

What can be happening? Is there a way to get precise execution of timed methods on iPhone???

thanks.

Comment: just to clarify. Do you use the simulator and NSLog or is it run on an actual iPhone?

Comment: I am using an actual iphone 4.

Comment: Have you tried the CADisplayLink API?  Is your app performing other activities on the same thread or run loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dispatch_source_t aTimer = CreateDispatchTimer(0.16 * NSEC_PER_SEC, //0.16 ms
                           0.048 * NSEC_PER_SEC, //30% tolerance
                           dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^{ MyPeriodicTask(); });
```

You are using Main Queue for firing the function. It means that the function is executed from the RunLoop on the main thread. The execution timing depends on tasks of the RunLoop. If MyPeriodicTask is able to be executed on a background thread, use Global Queue instead of Main Queue.

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
```

Still, it might be unstable even using Global Queue. I think CADisplayLink is more stable.

- [CADisplayLink Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

Luckily, CADisplayLink's framerate is 60fps on iOS. It is equal to 16.6ms what you want.

Comment: I have tried both options and CADisplayLink works better for what I need. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Doesn't the CADisplayLink callback come in on the Main Queue too?

Comment: It depends on the runloop which is specified by CADisplayLink addToRunLoop:forMode: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CADisplayLink/addToRunLoop:forMode: . If you use [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] on the main thread for the method, it means CADisplayLink callback will be fired on the main thread.